# Web page doesn't generate output for three minutes and dies. Where is the connection dying?

Tags: python, apache, timeout

I have a python script that generates a web page. The script does not generate any output at all for at least three minutes, so the browser stops before the page loads.

Where is this timeout occurring? Is it the browser giving up? Is it Apache serving the page timing out?

More importantly, is there a way to control this timeout to allow the page to load?

My workaround is to have a space character sent to the browser every 30 seconds or so to keep the page alive, but that is an ugly hack.

Running Apache 2.4.6 on Red Hat Enterprise 7.6 with Python 3.7.

Comment: apache config likely has a timeout (the browser doesnt time out as long as the connection is "alive" afaik)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

It was as simple as adding a TimeOut value to the httpd.conf file and restarting the httpd service.